# SSRS - Export report to Excel -HTML issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Here is my SSRS report. I set the placeholder as HTML

[image: SSRS Report]

I export my report to Excel. First I thought something is wrong with the note. But, when I click on the cell, it shows me my note. Is there anyway to display all the note in separate cell when exporting my report?

Excel Version:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the label mutli row or word wrap then you set the label's "CanGrow" property to false and if you are inside of a column group put the label inside of a rectangle and the set "CanGrow" to false.

Comment: That didn't do anything to excel file. If I changed "CanGrow" to false, then my report won't display those note properly